# Obtain SSL certificate information as PostgreSQL client

Tags: postgresql

I'm running a managed PostgreSQL database, which has SSL encryption turned on by the service provider. This is all working fine.

Now I need to obtain some information on the algorithms used for SSL (and key length, etc.). How I get this as a client (similar to how you can inspect certificates for web pages in Firefox)?

Best
Lars

Comment: [pg_stat_ssl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-SSL-VIEW) or the [sslinfo](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sslinfo.html) extension

Comment: Awesome, thank you